# Can't for loop through a whole list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, division, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to code in python to filter a list of the first n integers that when divided have a remainder of 1.  However, it looks like it's not checking every integer in my list according to the print statements I have.  I have no idea why. I'm just starting to learn code, so please be patient with me.  I suspect its something obvious I'm not seeing.

Below is my code I have so far:

```
def main():
    checkUpTo = 20
    listOfInts = list(range(checkUpTo))
    filterList = [3]
    boolList = []
    
    for d in filterList:
        print("checking list: " + str(listOfInts) + " for rem=1 when divided by " + str(d))
        for x in listOfInts:
            print("checking: " + str(x))
            isDivisible = checkIfDivisible(x,d)
            if isDivisible==False:
                listOfInts.remove(x)
        print("got list: " + str(listOfInts))

    print(listOfInts)

def checkIfDivisible(number,divisor):
    remainder = number % divisor
    print(str(number) + "%" + str(divisor) + "=" + str(remainder))
    if number % divisor == 1:
        return True
    if number % divisor != 1:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks for the help

edit: my output:

```
checking list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] for rem=1 when divided by 3
checking: 0
0%3=0
checking: 2
2%3=2
checking: 4
4%3=1
checking: 5
5%3=2
checking: 7
7%3=1
checking: 8
8%3=2
checking: 10
10%3=1
checking: 11
11%3=2
checking: 13
13%3=1
checking: 14
14%3=2
checking: 16
16%3=1
checking: 17
17%3=2
checking: 19
19%3=1
got list: [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19]
```

not sure why it's not checking 1,3, etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example input and the expected output?

Comment: a list of ints from 0 to n and a filter list.  for example, if the filter list is [2,3] and i'm checking the integers 1 to 10.  first i get [3,5,7,9] because each one is one more than a divisor by 2.  then, checking 3, it would be [7] because it is one more than a divisor of 7.  I'll add the output i get into the post.

Comment: You should not modify the list while you are iterating over it. Have a look at this question and ist answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at For loop, `listOfInts.remove(x)` removes element from list. Therefore, your list dose not have those element whose remainder is one.

```
 for x in listOfInts:
        print("checking: " + str(x))
        isDivisible = checkIfDivisible(x, d)
        if isDivisible == False:
             listOfInts.remove(x)
```

---

Lets understand what is hapening in for loop,

- List contain element from 0 to 19.
- for loop takes 0 and pass it to `checkIfDivisible` function.
- 0%3=0 returns `False`.
- `isDivisible == False`, so `listOfInts.remove(x)` removes element from position 0.
- for loop now fetches next item, since we have removed item from 0 position now at 0 position we have element 1 at 1 position we have elemt 2 and so on.
- therefore print statement doesnot display element 1.

  ```
   for x in listOfInts:
       print("checking: " + str(x))
       isDivisible = checkIfDivisible(x, d)
       print(isDivisible)
       if isDivisible == False:
           print(x)
           print(listOfInts)
           listOfInts.remove(x)
  ```

  checking: 0
  0%3=0
  False
  0
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
  checking: 2
  2%3=2
  False
  2
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

Comment: isDivisible is returning True if the remainder is 1, yes? (because number % divisor == 1) so why would it execute the if statement?

Comment: I have explain it above.   Sorry could not format code. getting error.

Comment: Awesome, that's really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`listOfInts.remove(x)` changes the object (`listOfInts`) you're iterating over in `for`, which will change the number of iterations in the loop.

Consider:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for index, value in enumerate(l):
    print(l)
    l.remove(value)

print(index + 1) # 3, not 5.
```

Rather than removing elements from `listOfInts`, iterate over `x in range(checkUpTo)`, and if you find a value that *is* divisible by `d`, add it to a `set`.

Comment: I see that listOfInts.remove(x) changes the list, but I'm not worried about the number of iterations changing.  but from output it looks like it's not checking 3%3=0 when it does the inner for loop over listOfInts.